# Parallel AC Sources

Tags: power, ac, inverter, parallel, dc-ac

[image]

Hello. I am new to electricity. I currently have 3 DC-AC inverter to drive 3 EL Wires(electroluminescent). The **input** of the inverter will be 12VDC and the **output** will be 90VAC. I would like to ask what if I use 3 of these inverters to connect 4 or more EL Wires in parallel? The real question is, what would happen if a load is connected to multiple AC power sources connected in parallel? What exact properties will the circuit have? Feel free to ask for more informations.

Answer (score 5):

If they are not specifically designed to be synchronized to each other and connected in parallel, then you cannot connect them in parallel - they will destroy each other.